# How do i remove <tbody> tags from an HTML table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Just like the title says: I need a way to remove the  tags from nested HTML tables. Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't see it happening I'm afraid - most browsers will inject them if they're missing. They're kind of an essential component to tables.

Comment: what did the `<tbody>` tags ever do to you!? :O

Comment: Whats the down vote for? It a perfectly valid question. Anyway, im trying to user jquery sortable on an HTML table which has nested tables. The nested tbody seems to mess it up.

Comment: You could have said so, then your question wouldn't have been downvoted so much.

Comment: I still think the down votes are unwarranted. Seems like they were cast by programming pedants who get off on that sort of thing. Thanks for the answer BoltClock.

Comment: If you could show us some code, you might be able to get an answer specific enough to solve your problem. Otherwise, if one of our answers is satisfactory you can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You can't disembody HTML tables.

If you're looking to get rid of superfluous `<tbody></tbody>` tags in an HTML string, do a string replacement:

```
var html = '<table><tbody>...</tbody></table>'.replace(/<\/?tbody>/g, '');
$(html).appendTo('body');
```

But browsers are still going to put the table rows in a table body when rendering the HTML anyway.

Comment: No it doesn't -- `<table>` is allowed to have `<tr>` children : http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/table.html

Comment: @Joe: Welp, I had a brain fart. It is to my knowledge that browsers still put `<tr>`s in a `<tbody>`, though.

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that, if you have no `<tbody>` in the source HTML, some browsers will definitely put it there, I know Chrome does. However, if you create the `<tr>` and `<td>` elements in JS and append them, it doesn't create the `<tbody>` for you:  http://jsfiddle.net/nwellcome/SJyWq/

Comment: @nwellcome: Fascinating - this is why I need to start writing tests. Thanks for your diligent research :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try jquery `remove()` function ?

Comment: That removes the table body *along with all the rows*.

Comment: @BoltClock, to be fair, Tester did not make clear whether this is what he wanted to do or not. Heck, he never said this was even supposed to happen in a browser, in which case I say use sed: `$sed -i 's/<[\/]*tbody>//g' file.html`