# How To Get Rid Of <tbody> and </tbody> HTML Table Tags But Not Remove The Content Inside The Tags?

Tags: php, html, html-table, html-tbody

I've taken a look at some of the other questions about removing table tbody tags (see below) but am still stuck on a problem.

[<tbody> tag displays in chrome but not source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34024136/tbody-tag-displays-in-chrome-but-not-source)

[Javascript delete a table tbody tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34933288/javascript-delete-a-table-tbody-tag)

[How do i remove <tbody> tags from an HTML table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856321/how-do-i-remove-tbody-tags-from-an-html-table)

After performing an SQL query, I want to generate an HTML table with the results, and then group similar rows by wrapping them in tbody /tbody tags in order to color-code the groups using CSS odd/even notation.

My javascript function to do this works fine, but the problem is that when the rows are first generated, the Chrome browser is wrapping them in tbody /tbody tags. So in the end I am left with the HTML below with an extra set of outer tbody tags (which is messing up the column alignment in the table and not displaying properly).

(* I want to get rid of the outer set of tbody tags *)

```
<tbody>
   <tbody></tbody>
   <tbody></tbody>
   <tbody></tbody>
   <tbody></tbody>
   <tbody></tbody>
</tbody>
```

I realize I could work some logic into the php being used to display the table rows to begin with, and try to insert the opening and closing tbody tags that way so that the outer set is never generated, but it's a bit cleaner just displaying all the rows and then grouping them afterwards.

Is it possible to remove the outer tbody tags without removing the content between them? Thanks.

html file

```html
    <!-- start all funds table -->
    <table id="all_funds_table" data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle" class="table 
      table-sm table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ng</th>
                <th>FID</th>
                <th>Lid</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <!-- <tbody> -->
            <?php                
                if ($result = $connection->query($sql)) {
                    
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        // only display rows with ng = 1
                        if ($row['ng'] == 1) {
            ?>
                            <tr class="gpRep">
                                <td style = "text-align: center"><?= $row['ng'] ?></td>
                                <td style = "text-align: center"><a href="group.php?FID=<?php echo $row['FID']; ?>"><?= $row['FID'] ?></a></td>
                                <td style = "text-align: center"><a href="fund.php?lid=<?php echo $row['lid']; ?>"><?= $row['lid'] ?></a></td>
                            </tr>                  

            <?php
                        // collapse rows with ng != 1
                        } else {
            ?>

                            <tr class="collapse">
                                <td style = "text-align: center"><?= $row['ng'] ?></td>
                                <td style = "text-align: center"><a href="group.php?FID=<?php echo $row['FID']; ?>"><?= $row['FID'] ?></a></td>
                                <td style = "text-align: center"><a href="fund.php?lid=<?php echo $row['lid']; ?>"><?= $row['lid'] ?></a></td>
                            </tr>  
            
            <?php

                        } // end if ($row['ng'] == 1)

                    } // end while
                    $result->free();
                } // end if
            
                if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
                }
                
                $connection->close();
            ?>
            <!-- close connection  -->
            <!-- </tbody> -->
            <script type="text/javascript">
                wrapRows();
            </script>
        </table>
    <!-- end all funds table -->
```

js file

```
function wrapRows(){
    $('#all_funds_table tr.gpRep').each(function(){
        $(this).nextUntil('.gpRep').add(this).wrapAll('<tbody />');
    });
}
```

Comment: Chrome tries to fix your markup if it's malformed. If the markup you're seeing in the browser isn't what you intended to be there, there's a bug in your html.

Comment: Add the correct `tbody` tags in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

## Using Javascript

Embrace the required `<tbody>` and instead move the rows outside of it as you iterate over them. Remove the original `<tbody>` when complete.

Note the need to add the first row back after calling `nextUntil` in each case.

```
$('#all_funds_table tr.gpRep').each(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('.gpRep').addBack().wrapAll('<tbody />')
        .parent().appendTo($('#all_funds_table'));
});
$('#all_funds_table tbody:first').remove();
```

## Using PHP

There really isn't any good reason not to output the `<tbody>` tags in the first place. This will save processing time in the browser.

```
    <?php                
        if ($result = $connection->query($sql)) {
            $first = true;
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                // only display rows with ng = 1
                if ($row['ng'] == 1) {
                    if (!$first) { echo '</tbody>'; }
                    $first = false;
    ?>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr class="gpRep">
                        <td style = "text-align: center"><?= $row['ng'] ?></td>
                        <td style = "text-align: center"><a href="group.php?FID=<?php echo $row['FID']; ?>"><?= $row['FID'] ?></a></td>
                        <td style = "text-align: center"><a href="fund.php?lid=<?php echo $row['lid']; ?>"><?= $row['lid'] ?></a></td>
                    </tr>                  

    <?php
                // collapse rows with ng != 1
                } else {
    ?>

                    <tr class="collapse">
                        <td style = "text-align: center"><?= $row['ng'] ?></td>
                        <td style = "text-align: center"><a href="group.php?FID=<?php echo $row['FID']; ?>"><?= $row['FID'] ?></a></td>
                        <td style = "text-align: center"><a href="fund.php?lid=<?php echo $row['lid']; ?>"><?= $row['lid'] ?></a></td>
                    </tr>  
    
    <?php

                } // end if ($row['ng'] == 1)

            } // end while
            $result->free();
        } // end if
    
        if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
        }
        
        $connection->close();
    ?>
    <!-- close connection  -->
    <!-- </tbody> -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        wrapRows();
    </script>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This mix of HTML and PHP isn't particularly easy to read. Depending how much data you have to output, you may find it neater to first load the information into an array in the format you want, then convert the array to HTML output.

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt. I was thinking that if the tbody tags themselves couldn't be removed, then I could move the rows outside of them and then just delete the original tbody element, but I wasn't sure how to do this. Your javascript solution works perfectly. And I agree with you that the mix of html and php is a bit difficult to read. I'll consider loading the desired output into an array first. Thanks again.

Comment: ended up going with this solution to display, hide, and color-code the rows, which does away with the multiple sets of body tags. but thanks again for your help Matt.

$odd = false;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     if ($row['ng'] == 1) {
          $odd = !$odd;
      } // end if ($row['ng'] == 1)?>
                        <tr class="<?  echo ($row['ng'] == 1 ? "gpRep": "collapse"); ?> <?  echo ($odd ? "odd": "even"); ?>">
                         </tr>